# How to make textview in expandable listview MATCH_PARENT

Tags: android, textview, expandablelistview

I am working on three level expandable list view. Everything works perfectly expect that the width of the textview of the second and third level of the expandable listview is wrapping its content and not matching the parent as I've specified in the layout.

Here is my code for Parent Level Adapter:

```
public class ParentLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<String> mListDataHeader;
    private final Map<String, List<String>> mListData_SecondLevel_Map;
    private final Map<String, List<String>> mListData_ThirdLevel_Map;
    private List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
    Activity activity;

    public ParentLevelAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mListDataHeader) {
        activity = (Activity) mContext;
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListDataHeader = new ArrayList<>();
        this.mListDataHeader.addAll(mListDataHeader);
        // SECOND LEVEL
        String[] mItemHeaders = new String[0];
        mListData_SecondLevel_Map = new HashMap<>();
        int parentCount = mListDataHeader.size();
         mItemHeaders = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array_expandable_level_two);
         mListData_SecondLevel_Map.put(mListDataHeader.get(i), Arrays.asList(mItemHeaders));

        }
        // THIRD LEVEL
        String[] mItemChildOfChild;
        mListData_ThirdLevel_Map = new HashMap<>();
        for (Object o : mListData_SecondLevel_Map.entrySet()) {
            Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry) o;
            Object object = entry.getValue();
            if (object instanceof List) {
                Collections.addAll(stringList, (String[]) ((List) object).toArray());
                mItemChildOfChild = mContext.getResources().getStringArray(R.array.items_array);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
    {
        final CustomExpandableListView secondLevelExpListView = new CustomExpandableListView(this.mContext);
        String parentNode = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        secondLevelExpListView.setAdapter(new SecondLevelAdapter(this.mContext, mListData_SecondLevel_Map.get(parentNode), mListData_ThirdLevel_Map));
        secondLevelExpListView.setGroupIndicator(null);
        secondLevelExpListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if (groupPosition != previousGroup)
                    secondLevelExpListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        });

        secondLevelExpListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                return false;
            }
        });
        return secondLevelExpListView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.mListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable, parent, false);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Second level Adapter code:

```
public class SecondLevelAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter 
{
    private final Context mContext;
    private final List<String> mListDataHeader;
    private final Map<String, List<String>> mListDataChild;

    public SecondLevelAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> mListDataHeader, Map<String, List<String>> mListDataChild) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mListDataHeader = mListDataHeader;
        this.mListDataChild = mListDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition,
                             boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_third, parent, false);
        }
        TextView txtListChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListThird);
        txtListChild.setText(childText);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        try {
            return this.mListDataChild.get(this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return this.mListDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return this.mListDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.expandable_list_second, parent, false);
        }
        TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

and my list row code which just contains the one textbox is

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/lblListThird"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_35sdp"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/_20sdp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:gravity="center|start" />
```

To be more precise i am uploading a picture which will give a clear view of what i am trying to say. Please have a look at it. I've turned on the "show layout bounds" from developer option which shows that my textview is only wrapping the content of the text and not matching parent. I want the textview to be clickable throughout and not till just the length of the text. [image]

Please tell me what I am doing wrong and what needs to be done to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's viewing this now or in the future. I solved it by removing the code which calculates the width. I don't know if this is the right way to go but it does get the job done. Here is the code snippet:

```
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec)
{
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(999999, MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```